# Detecting focus lost in Android Chrome using the home button

Tags: android, google-chrome, focus, dom-events

How can you use Javascript to detect that the browser is no longer the foreground app in Android? Currently, the known methods of "onblur" and "onfocus" are working when the window is navigated away from and to another tab, but not if the entire browser loses focus. Is there an event to listen for when the browser is closed using the home button?